# Как в slick-slider правильно изменять размеры боковых слайдов, чтобы не ломался слайдер?

Tags: html, css, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу победить этот слайдер. Подскажите, может есть какие-то советы как правильно кастомизировать слайдеры под себя? Нужно настроить слайдер так, чтоб у центрального слайда была ширина и высота отличающаяся от слайдов по бокам. А потом нужно их раскинуть как на фото. Как такое можно сделать? Настраивать теневые классы слика или изменять стили блоков в css? Буду рад любой помощи. `


Our professionals

```
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">David Robertson</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer with 5 years of experience</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-2.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">David Robertson</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer with 5 years of experience</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">David Robertson</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer with 5 years of experience</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-2.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">David Robertson</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer with 5 years of experience</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>`
```

`https://codepen.io/Loremord/pen/eYQMbJm`

Comment: Мой совет, не используйте Слик, возьмите например Свайпер, там такое проще реализовать.